# EWS API (Java) OAuth not working

Tags: java, api, oauth, office365, exchangewebservices

I am facing an issue with EWS OAuth, my requirement is to access mailbox of other users(EWS permissions are set). I got oauth2 authorization token and trying to do:

```
    service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");
    service.autodiscoverUrl("<email id>", new RedirectionUrlCallback());
```

and I get this error: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.exception.AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't get an oAuth Token that will work against the Autodiscover endpoint in office365 (Autodiscover and EWS are different webservices so EWS permissions won't do). You don't really need to do an autodisccover in Office365 as the endpoint will should be https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Glen is as usual right. You cannot do "classic" autodiscovery with OAUTH (although there is a separate OAUTH friendly Discovery api for REST and Office365 - but that only helps for REST APIS). You need to know the user is using Office365 and hardcode the EWS url. Then what you say is ok